# Group of units of the maximal order modulo its principal ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, proof-explanation, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am studying the proof of Proposition 1 presented in [this paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYqit.jpg). I am stuck at the following highlighted lines. Can anyone please help me understand the math behind them? Any help would be appreciated.

Also, when posting this question, I could not give an English description of $(\mathcal{O}_K/p\mathcal{O}_K)^\star$. How do I describe that unit group in English for the title or when I am presenting it in a group discussion?

[image]

Comment: -1. Please post all the relevant information. We have no idea what even the statement is that the proof is for! As it stands, we have no idea if $K$ is a general number field or just a quadratic field, what additional assumptions.